# How to divide X share rank wise?

Tags: python, math

There is a X sum and I have to find out share of Nth person according to their ranks. For example:

```
There are 5 persons (N) and amount is said to be 100 (X).
Now the first person gets the most and last person gets the least, and other gets according to their rank wise in order. Like this:
1st -> 30
2nd -> 25
3rd -> 20
4th -> 15
5th -> 10
```

There could be other possible combination of dividing this share rank wise, but that won't be much fair division either first rank would be getting most and others less, so I am seeking a formula which make it sure division is fair enough to be rank wise.

This is need to be done in Python. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are all values to be multiples of 5? Are the values to be a decreasing arithmetic sequence? Just what do you mean by "fair enough"? In your example, would the values `22,21,20,19,18` suffice? Just what kind of output do you want: a function returning the share of the Nth person, a list, a printout, other? Finally, what code have you tried?

Comment: @Rory, It should be Decreasing arithmetic sequence, I used 5 just for example.

Comment: What is "fair enough to be rank wise"? As long as you don't specify that more exactly, the programming question can't be answered.

Comment: @Rhymoid, I can code it myself I just need the formula for such arithmetic sequence.  
By Fair Enough I meant: first rank would be getting most and others very less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the division is to be such that the difference is constant, you know that the middle person (`N/2`) will get `X / N`. The person at `N/2-1` will get `X / N + difference`, `N/2-2` will get `X / N + 2*difference`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I was looking forward.